# VS 2010 and atl attributes - deprecated or not?

Tags: c++, com, atl

are atl attributes deprecated for VS 2010 or not? it seems they have been for VS 2008, 
but then I've found a lot of examples for atl attributes on msdn for VS 2010. 
have they maybe been "fixed" for 2010?

Comment: attributed ATL - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301337.aspx

Comment: also mentioned in ATL Internals: Working with ATL 8, Second Edition

Comment: Greetings from 2021. ATL attributes are still not deprecated, apparently.